# docker jenkins volume get reset in wsl on every windows restart

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm following a tutorial and trying to install jenkins with docker. In the tutorial it's trying to install the container in ubuntu system using aws server whereas i'm trying to install on my local wsl docker desktop using windows command prompt here is my dockerfile

```
# Use the Jenkins LTS image as the base image
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

USER root

# Install Docker dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common

# Add Docker's official GPG key
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -

# Add Docker repository
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

# Install Docker
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

# Add the jenkins user to the docker group
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins

RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/jenkins_home
```

after this I run the below commands

```
docker build -t jenkins-docker .
```

```
docker run -u 0 -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name jenkins -d jenkins-docker
```

it works fine I created new password even installed all recommended plugins and even after container restart the volume is retained it does not asks me to set user again in jenkins but when I restart my windows machine and start jenkins again it tells me set password and all those steps again.

Can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: might be bug in windows docker 
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/938

Comment: -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home can you tell is this correct how it will resolve the path in windows machine

Comment: enter "\\wsl$" into File Explorer's address bar to access your WSL folder

Comment: as i know when you use wsl  it will not use directly windows machine. it uses middle VM with linux